# Mocking a subprocess call in Python

Tags: python, mocking, subprocess, python-unittest

I have a method - `run_script()` - I would like to test. Specifically, I want to test that a call to [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) occurs. It would be even better to test that `subprocess.Popen` is called with certain parameters. When I run the test however I get `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.

How can I test my method to ensure that `subprocess` is actually being called using mocks?

```py
@mock.patch("subprocess.Popen")
def run_script(file_path):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["myscript", -M, file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = process.communicate()
    return process.returncode


def test_run_script(self, mock_subproc_popen):
    mock_subproc_popen.return_value = mock.Mock(
        communicate=("ouput", "error"), returncode=0
    )
    am.account_manager("path")
    self.assertTrue(mock_subproc_popen.called)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It seems unusual to me that you use the patch decorator over the `run_script` function, since you don't pass a mock argument there.

How about this:

```py
from unittest import mock
import subprocess

def run_script(file_path):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["myscript", -M, file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = process.communicate()
    return process.returncode


@mock.patch("subprocess.Popen")
def test_run_script(self, mock_subproc_popen):
    process_mock = mock.Mock()
    attrs = {"communicate.return_value": ("output", "error")}
    process_mock.configure_mock(**attrs)
    mock_subproc_popen.return_value = process_mock
    am.account_manager("path")  # this calls run_script somewhere, is that right?
    self.assertTrue(mock_subproc_popen.called)
```

Right now, your mocked subprocess.Popen seems to return a tuple, causeing process.communicate() to raise `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.`. Therefore it's most important to get the return_value on mock_subproc_popen just right.

Answer (score 1):

The [testfixtures](https://pypi.org/project/testfixtures/) library ([docs](https://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/popen.html), [github](https://github.com/Simplistix/testfixtures/)) can mock the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) package.

Here's an example on using the mock [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from testfixtures.mock import call
from testfixtures import Replacer, ShouldRaise, compare
from testfixtures.popen import MockPopen, PopenBehaviour


class TestMyFunc(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.Popen = MockPopen()
        self.r = Replacer()
        self.r.replace(dotted_path, self.Popen)
        self.addCleanup(self.r.restore)

    def test_example(self):
        # set up
        self.Popen.set_command("svn ls -R foo", stdout=b"o", stderr=b"e")

        # testing of results
        compare(my_func(), b"o")

        # testing calls were in the right order and with the correct parameters:
        process = call.Popen(["svn", "ls", "-R", "foo"], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
        compare(Popen.all_calls, expected=[process, process.communicate()])

    def test_example_bad_returncode(self):
        # set up
        Popen.set_command("svn ls -R foo", stdout=b"o", stderr=b"e", returncode=1)

        # testing of error
        with ShouldRaise(RuntimeError("something bad happened")):
            my_func()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the mocked object was called with a certain parameter, you can add the `side_effect` argument to the `mock.patch` decorator.

The return value of the `side_effect` function determines the return value of `subprocess.Popen`. If the `side_effect_func` returns DEFAULT, `subprocess.Popen` will be called in a normal way.

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from unittest.mock import DEFAULT
import subprocess


def run_script(script_path, my_arg):
    process = subprocess.Popen([script_path, my_arg])
    return process


def side_effect_func(*args, **kwargs):

    # Print the arguments
    print(args)
    
    # If 'bar' is contained within the arguments, return 'foo'
    if any(['bar' in arg for arg in args]):
        return 'foo'
    
    # If 'bar' is not contained within the arguments, run subprocess.Popen
    else:
        return DEFAULT


class TestRunScriptClass(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("subprocess.Popen", side_effect=side_effect_func)
    def test_run_script(self, mock):
        # Run the function
        process = run_script(script_path='my_script.py', my_arg='bar')
        
        # Assert if the mock object was called
        self.assertTrue(mock.called)
        
        # Assert if the mock object returned 'foo' when providing 'bar'
        self.assertEqual(process, 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for anything complex. You can simply move the call to subprocess to a function and pass a mock function in your test.

```
import subprocess
import unittest
import logging

from unittest.mock import Mock


def _exec(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return p, stdout, stderr


def uses_exec(execute=_exec):
    cmd = ['ls']
    p, stdout, stderr = execute(cmd)
    if p.returncode != 0:
        logging.error(
            '%s returned Error Code: %s',
            cmd,
            p.returncode
        )
        logging.error(stderr)
    else:
        logging.info(stdout)


class TestUsesExecute(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_aws_creds_from_namespace(self):
        p = lambda:None
        p.returncode = 0
        stdout = 'file1  file2'
        mock_execute = Mock(return_value=(p, stdout, ''))
        uses_exec(execute=mock_execute)
        mock_execute.assert_called_with(['ls'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This pattern works in all programming languages that allow functions to be passed as parameters. It can be used with other python system calls for file and network reads just as easily.

Comment: This pattern adds implementation details to your function's public interface.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for a test suite where there were many [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) calls to check.

```py
import contextlib
import re
import subprocess
from typing import NamedTuple
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class CmdMatch(NamedTuple):
    cmd: str
    match: str = ".*"
    result: str = ""
    side_effect: Callable = None


@contextlib.contextmanager
def mock_run(*cmd_match: Union[str, CmdMatch], **kws):
    sub_run = subprocess.run
    mock = MagicMock()
    if isinstance(cmd_match[0], str):
        cmd_match = [CmdMatch(*cmd_match, **kws)]

    def new_run(cmd, **_kws):
        check_cmd = " ".join(cmd[1:])
        mock(*cmd[1:])
        for m in cmd_match:
            if m.cmd in cmd[0].lower() and re.match(m.match, check_cmd):
                if m.side_effect:
                    m.side_effect()
                return subprocess.CompletedProcess(cmd, 0, m.result, "")
        assert False, "No matching call for %s" % check_cmd

    subprocess.run = new_run
    yield mock
    subprocess.run = sub_run
```

So now you can write a test like this:

```py
def test_call_git():
    with mock_run("git", "describe.*", "v2.5") as cmd:
        do_something()
        cmd.assert_called_once()


def test_other_calls():
    with mock_run(
        CmdMatch("git", "describe.*", "v2.5"),
        CmdMatch("aws", "s3.*links.*", side_effect=subprocess.CalledProcessError),
    ) as cmd:
        do_something()
```

Couple funky things you might want to change, but I liked them:

- the resulting mock calls ignore the first argument (so which/full-paths aren't part of the tests)
- if nothing matches any calls, it asserts (you have to have a match)
- the first positional is considered the "name of the command"
- kwargs to run are ignored (_call assertions are easy but loose)