# mocking subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, subprocess

I have a module utils.py which has this run_cmd() method

```
def run_cmd(cmd):
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                            shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(pipe.communicate())
    print(pipe.returncode)
    stdout, stderr = [stream.strip() for stream in pipe.communicate()]
    output = ' - STDOUT: "%s"' % stdout if len(stdout) > 0 else ''
    error = ' - STDERR: "%s"' % stdout if len(stderr) > 0 else ''
    logger.debug("Running [{command}] returns: [{rc}]{output}{error}".format(
                 command=cmd,
                 rc=pipe.returncode,
                 output=output,
                 error=error))

    return pipe.returncode, stdout, stderr
```

I wrote a unit-test using mock and this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692440/mocking-a-subprocess-call-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) as a reference

```
  @patch('subprocess.Popen')
  @patch('utils.logger.debug')
  def test_run_cmd(self, mock_popen, mock_log):
    cmd = 'mock_command'
    mocked_pipe = Mock()
    attrs = {'communicate.return_value': ('output', 'error'), 'returncode': 0}
    mocked_pipe.configure_mock(**attrs)
    mock_popen.return_value = mocked_pipe
    log_calls = [call('Running [mock_command] returns: [0]outputerror')]
    utils.run_cmd(cmd)
    mock_popen.assert_called_once_with(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    mock_log.assert_has_calls(log_calls)
```

I got this as output when I run the nosetest

```
        stdout, stderr = [stream.strip() for stream in pipe.communicate()]
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
<MagicMock name='Popen().communicate()' id='140197276165008'>
<MagicMock name='Popen().returncode' id='140197276242512'>

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
FAILED (errors=1)
```

Why is the pipe.communicate() not printing the ('output', 'error') or the pipe.returncode not printing the 0, but their mock methods? Where did it go wrong? How could I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Ah, You already have an answer of your question. look closely and you will know why. You have to mock like you did for `logger`. You forgot to mention `utils` while creating mocked object.

```
@patch('utils.subprocess.Popen')
```

Now, mocking the nested function with multiple values, I think you should look at the [side_effects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523189/how-to-mock-nested-functions).

I haven't tested the below code but I hope it should work or at least give you some sort of lead.

```
mocked_open.return_value.communicate.return_value = ('output', 'error')
mocked_open.return_value.returncode = 0
```

Hope that will help!

Comment: I can mock the pipe.communicate() this way. `@patch('utils.subprocess.Popen.communicate', return_value=('output', 'error'))`       How can I mock the pipe.returncode?

Comment: Updated Answer to use `side_effects` and other

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I solved it finally. But I patched subprocess instead of subprocess.Popen.

`mock_subprocess.Popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = ('output', 'error')`
`mock_subprocess.Popen.return_value.returncode = 0`

Comment: Awesome. You made it!