# How to mock subprocess.run in pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, subprocess, pytest, pytest-mock

I have the class *InternalProc*, defined as following:

```
class InternalProc:

    @staticmethod
    def get_data():
        try:
            result = subprocess.run(['bridge-client', '--business-credentials'],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            data = json.loads(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
            return data
        except Exception:
            logger.error("Unable to fetch the data")
            raise
```

I want to unit test the `get_data()`, how should I mock `subprocess.run`? I also want to assert on whether the exception was raised or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking a subprocess call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692440/mocking-a-subprocess-call-in-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like you need two tests to test this method, one that returns data and one that raises an `Exception`.

For the one where we return data we simply need to mock `subprocess.run`. Then we can create another `Mock` object to mock `stdout.decode` to return data that `json.loads` can parse. This means creating a `Mock` object for the behavior of `stdout` and then configuring our mocked `subprocess.run` to use this object.

For the other test we simply need to use the `side_effect` kwarg of the `Mock` object to raise an exception when it is called.

Given the following folder structure:

```
stackoverflow/
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── proc.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_proc.py
```

The tests we write are shown below.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

import pytest

from mypackage.proc import InternalProc


@patch("mypackage.proc.subprocess.run")
def test_get_data_valid(mock_run):
    mock_stdout = MagicMock()
    mock_stdout.configure_mock(
        **{
            "stdout.decode.return_value": '{"A": 3}'
        }
    )

    mock_run.return_value = mock_stdout

    result = InternalProc.get_data()
    assert result == {"A": 3}


@patch("mypackage.proc.subprocess.run", side_effect=Exception("foobar"))
def test_get_data_invalid(mock_run):
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc:
        InternalProc.get_data()
        assert "foobar" in str(exc.value)
```

Output:

```
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ***/stackoverflow
collected 2 items                                                                                  

tests/test_proc.py ..                                                                        [100%]

======================================== 2 passed in 0.07s =========================================
```

My suggestion to you, since I have seen you post multiple `pytest`/`mock` questions in the last few days is to spend some time reading the documentation for both. Make some toy examples and play around with the two packages. That is the only way you will learn how to mock and where to mock.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I have been reading the documentation but since I am relatively new to python and completely new to unit testing, it is giving me a hard time. It will be really really great if you can help me with few more questions if there are any.

Comment: In the second test, where are we raising the exception? As in where are we calling the get_Data()?

Comment: @user8082934 I omitted a line accidentally in the second test, it should be updated now.

Comment: Please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516824/mocking-exception-pytest

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [pytest-subprocess](https://github.com/aklajnert/pytest-subprocess)